# VBA Excel - Delimit and Parse sections in Word Document in-order to input data into Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to figure out a way using VBA to parse a Word Document so I can put its contents into an array. For this example I have two companies in a Word Document (as seen below the code) and I want to put the fields into an array.

```
Public Sub ParseCompanies()

Dim Company_Array(1 To 2) As String 'stores individual company fields
Dim Companies_Array() 'array for all companies

Dim oWord As Object, oDoc As Object
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:/Temp/test.docx", Visible:=True)

Dim singleLine
Dim lineText As String

'need to rewrite this section
For Each singleLine In oDoc.Paragraphs

   lineText = singleLine.Range.Text
   Debug.Print lineText    

Next singleLine


End Sub
```

Word file contents cut and pasted onto Stack Overflow:

> ---
>
> Company:   Aladin Carpets
>
> Product:      Magic Carpets
>
> ---
>
> Company:   Aerials Seashells
>
> Product:      Seashells
>
> ---

The way the current script runs can be seen below in the VBA Debugger Output

[image]

Is there an efficient way to do this? A way to delimit the lines or section splitters in the word document in order to parse the individual companies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Solution:***

If the output is as stated -I copied your data but I get different results-, this should work, if not, just adjust the element being saved in the array:

```
Public Sub ParseCompanies()

Dim Products_Array() As String 'stores individual company fields
Dim Companies_Array() As String 'array for all companies
Dim CounterElements As Long: CounterElements = 1
Dim CounterParagraphs As Long

Dim oWord As Object, oDoc As Object
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
On Error GoTo Err01ParseCompanies
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\lz630z\Desktop\Company.docx", visible:=True)

Dim singleLine
Dim lineText As String

'need to rewrite this section
For CounterParagraphs = 1 To oDoc.Paragraphs.Count
   If InStr(oDoc.Paragraphs(CounterParagraphs).Range.Text, "Company") Then ReDim Preserve Companies_Array(CounterElements): Companies_Array(CounterElements) = oDoc.Paragraphs(CounterParagraphs + 2)
   If InStr(oDoc.Paragraphs(CounterParagraphs).Range.Text, "Product") Then ReDim Preserve Products_Array(CounterElements): Products_Array(CounterElements) = oDoc.Paragraphs(CounterParagraphs + 2): CounterElements = CounterElements + 1

Next CounterParagraphs

If 1 = 2 Then ' 99. If error
Err01ParseCompanies:
MsgBox "Word Error", vbCritical
End If '99. If error
Set oDoc = Nothing
Set oWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

***Summary of changes/suggestions***

`For each` won't work here, since according to the screenshot is going to be 2 rows after it found the first result, it's better to have everything controlled in this scenario and save the elements in the array accordingly, changed a `For/To` approach (I assumed you arrays meant to be as defined now).
Whenever you are referring to one, for the size the other will be accordingly.

IG: Companies_Array(1) will be Aladin Carpets and Products_Array(1) will be Magic Carpets

Answer (score 0):

If your word document items are truly paragraph delimited, you could use the [`Split`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/split.php) method to fill your array and then loop through it to manipulate the data. For example, this just fills the array and prints the elements to the immediate window:

```
Public Sub ParseCompanies()
    Dim wordList() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document

    Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\test\Desktop\Company.docx", Visible:=False)

    wordList = Split(oDoc.Content.Text, vbCr) 'split using carriage return (paragraphs)

    For i = 0 To UBound(wordList, 1)
        Debug.Print wordList(i)
    Next i

    oWord.Quit
End Sub
```

I can't speak to the performance of this method on a large file, so it may require testing before this can be considered a viable option.